# How to make images in WKInterfacePicker Transparent?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-watch

I have a WKInterfacePicker which is set to Sequence mode. When i add images to it during runtime and display it on the apple watch, the images seems to have a black background (instead of having the transparent pixels). The Images have transparent pixels in them. Here is the code i used in willActivate function:

```
NSMutableArray *pItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:31];

for(int i=0; i<30; ++i){
    WKPickerItem *item = [[WKPickerItem alloc] init];
    WKImage *img = nil;
    if(i < 10)
        img = [WKImage imageWithImageName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"safeDial_0%d", i]];
    else
        img = [WKImage imageWithImageName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"safeDial_%d", i]];

    [item setContentImage:img];
    [pItems addObject:item];
}

[self.pickerSafeLock setItems:[pItems copy]];
[self.pickerSafeLock setSelectedItemIndex:0];
[self.pickerSafeLock focus];
```

Note: pickerSafeLock is the WKInterfacePicker

Also, when i use the same images on a WKImage, i see that the transparent pixels work fine.

Is there a way to make the Images in WKInterfacePicker transparent?

Comment: I ran into the same issue just now. Do let me know if you find a solution. I have a nagging feeling there might not be one, other than using the "background image animation" trick as explained here: http://techotopia.com/index.php/A_WatchKit_WKInterfacePicker_Coordinated_Animation_Example#Configuring_the_Group_Background_Animation

Comment: More bad news: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5092

Comment: @DaGaMs: Thanks, that helps, i am trying to use a similar way. Also, i am working on another simple solution i think might work. It is not really optimized but i will post it once i get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying multiple ways (including @DaGaMs's solution), i found an considerably tricky solution to the problem. I have used a WKInterfacePicker and an associated WKInterfaceImage alongside it. Here is a way to overcome the issue:

In the Storyboard of your WatchKit App add a WKinterfaceImage, WKInterfaceGroup and WKInterfacePicker inside a WKInterfaceGroup.

Here is how it would look:

[image: Overcoming Transparency of WKInterfacePicker]

This is just to hide the Picker offscreen, so that we can fake the animation from the Picker to the WKInterfaceImage.

Once you do this, on the IBAction of WKInterfacePicker set the corresponding images like this:

```
- (IBAction)pickerAction:(NSInteger)value {
    [self.yourWKInteraceImage setImage:imgPickerList[value]];
}
```

Note: imgPickerList contains all the images that you want to animate (same as the Picker).

Comment: what's the benefit of doing it this way compared to the coordinated background animated image approach?

Comment: Well, the coordinated approach didnt seem to work unless the picker and group overlapped. Also, this gives a better control when you use the crown on every step on the picker. For example, if you want the images loop with a specific logic, you can write it yourself.